# Retrieving Content From WebClient.Download

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, webclient

I am uploading content to a website using Webclient.UploadData.

```
data ="GetCourses('all')"; //this will return all the courses in the course table.

WebClient wb= new WebClient();
try
{
   byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
   byte[] results = wb.UploadData(url, "POST", bytes);
   var returnResult = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(results);
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
   ex.ToString()
}
```

I am trying the get the data that was sent above on the other side. I am expected to see "GetCourses('all')", but it shows null ("")instead.

```
var requestData = Request.InputStream;
int length = Convert.ToInt32(requestData.Length);
byte[] strArr = new byte[length];

var strRead = requestData.Read(strArr, 0, length);
string content = string.Empty;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
   content = content + strArr[i].ToString();
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: As @SLaks said. `var str = new StreamReader(requestData).ReadToEnd();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Stream.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var requestData = Request.InputStream;
string str;

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
   requestData.CopyTo(ms);
   str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray);
}
```

Or as smarter people suggested, you can use a [`StreamReader.ReadToEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var streamReader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
var outputString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Thank you. You all are awesome. I've been doing this for less than 3 months, and I am learning so much from here.

Comment: @user3802347 You may upvote the answers which helped you, by pressing the upper arrow above the number to the left of the answer. Also, you may select the answer which helped you the most by selecting the hollow checkmark below the same voting counter, which will turn it green.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly in:

```
int length = Convert.ToInt32(requestData.Length)
```

I think you'll find that `requestData.Length` is already an `int`: converting it will just make the code confusing.

But your real problem is in decoding your byte stream. `byte.ToString()` will treat the `byte` value as a number, not as a character.

Use

```
content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(strArray)
```

to decode the UTF-8 data into a .NET string. (Note, if the content is long there are ways of doing this incrementally, but for short content that's not worth the effort.)

Also note [L.B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/932418/l-b)'s comment to the Q: you can also use a `StreamReader` (but I would be explicit about the encoding.)

Comment: I thought it was an int too, but it's actually a long;I had to do the conversation. I will use Encoding.UTF8.GetString(strArray) instead.

Comment: @user3802347 To convert `long` to `int` either cast (with an assertion in case of overflow) or update to use `long` throughout.